# Livewire Password Reset Component

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewires

The Laravel website states that you can use the following code to reset the users password

```
$request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
);

return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
            : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
```

I wanting to create the password reset function as a Livewire component and have used the following code

```
$this->validate();

    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $this->email
    );

    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
            : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
```

I keep getting the error message

> Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::sendResetLink(): Argument #1
> ($credentials) must be of type array, string given

I understand the message is asking for an array, but not sure how to fix it... Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sendResetLink` function expects an `array` where you're providing a `string`. The difference between the reference code and your code is the parameter type.

```
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
);
```

`$request->only('email')` returns an associative `array`, that will look like; `['email' => 'you@domain.com']`. This is provided to the `sendResetLink` function.

Compare that with your implementation.

```
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    $this->email
);
```

With your implementation you're only providing`you@domain.com`. What you want is to create an `array` that mimics the one returned by `$request->only('email')`, so;

```
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    ['email' => $this->email]
);
```